# Overlay one div over another on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two visualizations, each in different div. I want to place one div over another on button click to overlay and compare them. Then, on another button click, I want to separate it out. Any code snippet or links would be appreciated. Right now I am just trying to make use of the following javascript function:

```
function ShowOverlay(divID, xCoordinate, yCoordinate) {    
    var divObject = document.getElementById(divID);    
    divObject.style.visibility = "visible";    
    divObject.style.left = xCoordinate;    
    divObject.style.top = yCoordinate;    
}
```

Comment: the ideal solution depends on html of the div layer, the html of the div intended for overlay, the wrapper in case there is one, and of course some crucial css keeping them at default state. Because the ideal solution may be as simple as `[overlay div].style.position  = "absolute"` .

Answer (score 0):

you should use absolute or relative positioning.

If your `position` property is not set to `absolute` or `relative` `style.left` and `style.top` won't have any effect.

The following will allow them to move (you just need to work out the coordinates:

```
function ShowOverlay(divID, xCoordinate, yCoordinate) {

    var divObject = document.getElementById(divID);

    divObject.style.visibility = "visible";
    divObject.style.left = xCoordinate;
    divObject.style.top = yCoordinate;
    divObject.style.position = "absolute";

}
```

To undo it, simple set position back to static:

```
divObject.style.position = "static";
```

Comment: It still doesn't move. The overlay class is <style type="text/css">

.divOverlay {top:0px; left:0px; position:absolute; z-index:500;}

</style>          and the new coordinates are 100 and 200

Comment: sure. http://pastie.org/7705678 (The different sections show the relevant portions for my question - the divOverlay class, the JS overlay function, then if you scroll down, you will see the actual div class and the button. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that's a HUGE wall of code and not well formatted. It's a bit difficult to investigate like that. Would it be possible to create a jsfiddle? If you don't know jsfiddle, it's an online playground for JS, HTML and CSS. You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net If you try to reproduce the behavior there, I'll take a look at it and I will try to help you

Comment: Ok. I'll let you know once I put it up there. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! Looks like I was doing a stupid mistake with single and double quotes while specifying the coordinates. Works now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: OK, happy to help, please remember to accept the answer / up vote it if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple working example of moving three div's over one another on button click.
HTML code

```
<div class="container">
 <div class = "circlea"><h2>link</h2></div>
 <div class = "circleb"><h2>link</h2></div>
 <div class = "circlec"><h2>link</h2></div>
 <button >click me</button>
</div>


.circlea,.circleb,.circlec{
 height:150px;
 width:150px;
 border-radius:50%;
 margin-left:50%;
 margin-top:120px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 opacity:0;
 color:white;
 text-align:center; 
}

.circlea{
 background-color:rgba( 20, 155, 138 );
 }

.circleb{
 background-color:rgba( 155, 20, 144 );
}

.circlec{
 background-color:rgba( 24, 155, 20);
 opacity:1;
}

button{
 background-color:tomato;
 width:100px;
 padding:10px;
 color:white;
 }

.transforma{
 margin-left:200px;
 opacity:1;
 }

.transformb{
  margin-left:800px;
  opacity:1;
 }

.transformb{
 opacity:1;
 }
```

js

```
 $("button").click(function(){

  $("div.circleb").toggleClass("transformb");
  $("div.circlea").toggleClass("transforma");

 });
```

https://codepen.io/pranjalkoshti/pen/rYNQeL